# error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Tags: .net, nuget-package, webapi

[After trying to create new dotnet project there is some Nuget issue and I can't seem to fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eOCr.png)

I've tried multiple times to reinstalled .NET SDK and clean files but it keeps happening.

I tried to reinstall .NET Framework and remove any and all other .net projects I had. I think this all started when I deleted a line from my old .csproj file for one of the packages and tried to install postgresql entity framework package. I tried to also delete the nuget.config file told from another stackoverflow question, and that also didn't work.